# Does there exist a connected metric space $X$ such that for every connected subset $A$ of $X$ , $X \setminus A$ is nowhere dense in $X$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Does there exist a connected metric space $X$(with more than one point) such that for every connected subset  $A$ (with more than one point) of $X$ , $X \setminus A$ is nowhere dense in $X$, i.e. $ \operatorname{int}\left(  \overline {X \setminus A}\right)=\emptyset$  ?

Comment: Well $A$ could be a point. Or even empty...

Comment: @DustanLevenstein : Those are not considered ; any connected set is considered with more than one point

Comment: Then my guess is still no, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein : thank you for your comment ; please feel free to give any kind of input regarding the question . I would really like to see a proof or counterexample of the statement . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be such a set, but it has to have some properties.

The requirements on such a set is that connected sets has to be either "large" or trivial. Let $D(T)$ be the diameter of a non-empty set in $X$ (which can be infinite) if theres a connected set $A$ such that $1<D(A)<D(X)$ then there will be a point $b\in X$ such that $d(b,X)>0$ and therefore there's an open set surrounding $b$ not intersecting $A$ which means that $X\setminus A$ is not nowhere dense.

If for example $X$ is somewhere weakly locally connected we could construct such a set $A$. If the criterion for weakly locally connected is fulfilled for $a$ then we can just form a open ball with radius $D(X)/3$ which will contain a connected subset $A$ and $D(A)\le 2D(X)/3$.

Comment: " If $B_r(a)$ is connected , then it would only contain $a$" ; why is that ?

Comment: @user228169 I did the assumption that $A$ only contained one point and $A$ is the connected component of $B_r(a)$ that contains $a$. If $B_r(a)$ is connected this makes $A=B_r(a)$. The reasoning leads in both cases to $X$ being disconnected with contradicts the assumption.

Comment: how do you get an open set $B$ disjoint from $A$ such that $B_r(a)=A \cup B$ ? Why is $X \setminus B_{r/2}(a)$ open ?

Comment: @user228169 $B$ is disjoint from $A$ because that's under the assumption that $B_r(a)$ is not connected (then you can write it as disjoint union of two open sets). It should be $X\setminus C_{r/2}(a)$ that is after removing a closed ball from $X$ (I've corrected that), it's open then by the triangle inequality.

Comment: But is $A$ open ? I think $A$ is closed that's for sure ; so how do you get $B$ to be open ?

Comment: @user228169 $A$ is open as well. The (topological) definition of connectedness is that if it's not connected you can decompose it with disjoint open sets. Normally these could be supersets of the components, but in this case there's no points in the space not being part of the components so then the components need to be open. Maybe the confusion is that you're used to another definition of connectedness?

Comment: I'm well-aware of that definition ; still I don't seem to get the decomposition here :(

Comment: The Knaster-Kuratowski fan (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan ) is an example of a connected metric space $X$ such that the removal of any point makes it totally disconnected . Now your ball $B_r(a)$ is a subset of $X\setminus \{b\}$ , so $B_r(a)$ cannot contain any connected subset with more than one point i.e. any connected component of $B_r(a)$ (so in particular $A$) must be singleton . Am I right ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: On the q of why $B$ is open : The set $A$ is a component of $B_r(a$) so $A$ is open and closed in the subspace $B_r(a)$. With$\bar A$ denoting the closure of $A$ in $ X$,   with  $B_r(a)=D$,  we have $ D\backslash A=D\backslash  (Cl_D(A))=D \backslash (D\cap \bar A))=D\backslash \bar A$ which is open in $X$ . The set $A$ is not necessarily closed in $X$.

Comment: There is no contradiction at the end because the boundary of $C_{r/2} (a)$ is not necessarily empty.

Comment: @user228169 My mistake, I removed that part from the answer. I still think there's no such set, but I'm not that sure. I've included some requirements for such a set (which I find unlikely). The Knaster-Kuratowski fan is no candidate as it's weakly locally connected at $(1/2, 1/2)$.

Comment: @ForeverMozart OK, so they exists, but I don't think my argument is flawed because of that. What my argument was is that there's a connected subset of (strictly) smaller diameter then that connected subset is not everywhere dense. I don't really see how your example applies to that observation.

Comment: @skyking your assumption $D(A)<D(X)$ may not be valid.  $A$ could be a proper connected subset of $X$, but have the same diameter.

Comment: @ForeverMozart Perhaps, but the statement was that if $D(A)<D(X)$ then $A$ is not everywhere dense in $X$. Which means that $X$ cannot have such non-trivial connected subsets.